# How to display received data or value in Blazor webassembly?

Tags: c#-4.0, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I have this problem: I can send data or a value to a function from a page or an API but razer component doesn't show the value; actually, it doesn't render new values.

Here's my example function:

```
public string p="";
public void myMethod(string a)
{
    p=a;
}
```

Here's my HTML tag:

```
<p>@p</p>
```

When I click the button from an other page, `myMethod` will be called like this:

```
private void buttonClick()
{
    new NavMenu().myMethod("Test text");
}
```

The button click is in a page and `NavMenu` is a component. I debug this and the value of 'p' successfully changed but the page does not show new value.

Actually I tried this code but nothing happened:

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
```

What should I do to display new values without refreshing the page?

Comment: `public void myMethod(string a)
{
    p=a; InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}`

Comment: Thankyou @daniherrera. When I use this code, I got some error's

Comment: When you use this code, you are creating a new instance of the NavMenu class, calling the method, then just throwing it all away. `new NavMenu().myMethod("Test text");` You do not "new" up components like this in Blazor

Comment: Yes your right. but if I use static method then I can't call StateHasChanged()